# Copy all files of sub and nested sub directories

Tags: docker, directory, dockerfile

This is my project file structure:

```
java-project/
├── docker.compose.yml
├── pom.xml
└── services/
    ├── a/
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── pom.xml
    │   ├── src/
    │   │   ├── pom.xml
    │   │   ├── xxx
    │   │   └── xxx
    │   └── target/
    │       ├── pom.xml
    │       └── xxxx
    └── b/
        ├── Dockerfile
        ├── pom.xml
        ├── src/
        │   ├── pom.xml
        │   ├── xxx
        │   └── xxx
        └── target/
            ├── pom.xml
            └── xxxx
```

I want to copy all of the contents of the `services` folder of the project (including all the subfolders inside the `services`). Basically, I want to replicate the current project structure with every file and folder in the docker image as well for the `mvn` build to execute successfully.

I am doing the following in the Dockerfile, but I don't see all of the contents:

```
COPY services/**/pom.xml ./services/
```

What am I doing wrong here? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your `COPY` instruction:

```
#    <src>               <dest>
COPY services/**/pom.xml ./services/
```

Under the hood, Docker reads the `<src>` using [Go's `filepath.Match`](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match) method.  This means that the instruction doesn't use the globstar (`**`) the way glob patterns do.  However, your question suggests you want to copy everything inside `services` — not only `pom.xml` files.

You can copy everything inside your local `services` directory using:

```
COPY services ./services/
```

If you want to exclude certain subdirectories or files, you can specify this using a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).

Comment: thanks. how would I copy if I just wanted lets say the pom.xml file?

Comment: Using `services/a/pom.xml` as an example: `COPY services/a/pom.xml services/a/` or `COPY services/a/pom.xml services/a/pom.xml`